# REGEX de cadena alfanumérica que no permita SOLO numeros

Tags: javascript, regex, algoritmos

Tengo un problema a la hora de crear una expresión regular de una cadena alfanumérica de máximo 99 caracteres, pero que no la valide si esa cadena son solo números.

He estado probando con varias expresiones:

`^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿªº \s\-]{1,99}`

`^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿªº]+?$`

`^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*$`

Pero el problema es que a veces, si le pongo una cadena '*ajfrg[dwf*' no debería de validarla porque los corchetes no forman parte del rango alfanumérico. ¿Me falta algo por poner? ¿Hay alguna manera más simple?

Muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con alguna de estas debería funcionar:

- `^(?!\d*$)\w{1,99}$`
- `^(?!\d*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,99}$`
- `^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,99}$`

### Explicación

En esencia, los tres son prácticamente lo mismo, por trozos:

- Con `^` y `$` le decimos que vaya de principio a fin del `string`. El `^` para que lo sitúe en el principio y el `$` para el final
- `\d` significa lo mismo que `[0-9]`. Por lo tanto, el bloque `(?!\d*$)` en esencia dice que si encuentra un `string` que vaya desde el principio (por el `^`) hasta el fin del mismo solo de dígitos, no lo machee por el `?!`, básicamente significa que lo que machee el bloque no lo coja.
- En la segunda parte, el segundo y el tercero son iguales, pero el primero tiene una pequeña diferencia, esta diferencia es que  `\w` es igual a `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, mientras  que en los otros dos no tiene underscore (`_`) (No sé si este carácter te servirá, así que lo pongo y si no coges los otros). En esencia, esta segunda parte dice que machee todos los caracteres entre `a` y `z`, entre `A` y `Z` y finalmente `0` y `9`, sin estos últimos dígitos no machearía un `string` que contenga tanto letras como dígitos.
- Por último `{1,99}`, aquí le dices que el `string` tiene que tener entre 1 y 99 caracteres, si tiene 0 no sirve y si tiene 100 tampoco sirve.

Cualquier duda házmela saber y te la resuelvo sin problema.